# Redux reducer: Add object to array when the array doesn't have the object data

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to store AJAX call returned data object to an array of reducer state of Redux.
I have some conditions to check if the fetched data already exists inside of the reducer.

Here are my problems:

1. The component to call AJAX call actions, it's a function from `mapDispatchToProps`, causes an infinite loop.
2. `isProductLikedData` state in reducer doesn't get updated properly.

Can you tell what I'm missing?

Here are my code:

isProductLikedActions.js - action to fetch isProductLiked data. `response.data` looks like `{status: 200, isProductLiked: boolean}`

```
export function fetchIsProductLiked(productId) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    axios
      .get(`/ajax/app/is_product_liked/${productId}`)
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch({
          type: 'FETCH_IS_PRODUCT_LIKED_SUCCESS',
          payload: { ...response.data, productId },
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({
          type: 'FETCH_IS_PRODUCT_LIKED_REJECTED',
          payload: err,
        });
      });
  };
}
```

isProductLikedReducer.js - I add `action.payload` object to `isProductLikedData` array when `array.length === 0`. After that, I want to check if `action.payload` object exists in `isProductLikedData` or not to prevent the duplication. If there is not duplication, I want to do like `[...state.isProductLikedData, action.payload]`.

```
const initialState = {
  isProductLikedData: [],
  fetching: false,
  fetched: false,
  error: null,
};

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_IS_PRODUCT_LIKED': {
      return { ...state, fetching: true };
    }
    case 'FETCH_IS_PRODUCT_LIKED_SUCCESS': {
      return {
        ...state,
        fetching: false,
        fetched: true,
        isProductLikedData:
          state.isProductLikedData.length === 0
            ? [action.payload]
            : state.isProductLikedData.map((data) => {
                if (data.productId === action.payload.productId) return;
                if (data.productId !== action.payload.productId)
                  return action.payload ;
              }),
      };
    }
    case 'FETCH_IS_PRODUCT_LIKED_REJECTED': {
      return {
        ...state,
        fetching: false,
        error: action.payload,
      };
    }
  }

  return state;
}
```

Products.js - `products` is an array that fetched in `componentWillMount`. Once `nextProps.products.fetched` becomes true, I want to call `fetchIsProductLiked` to get isProductLiked` data. But this causes an infinite loop.

```
class Products extends React.Component {
 ...
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchProducts();
  }
 ...

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.products.fetched) {
      nextProps.products.map((product) => {
        this.props.fetchIsProductLiked(product.id);
    }
  }

  render() {
  ...
  }
}

export default Products;
```

Comment: can you show the code where you use connect for Products component to connect to redux store

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue 1

> The component to call AJAX call actions, it's a function from mapDispatchToProps, causes an infinite loop.

You are seeing **infinite** calls because of the condition you used in `componentWillReceiveProps`.

`nextProps.products.fetched` is **always** `true` after *products* (data) have been fetched. Also, note that `componentWillReceiveProps` will be called every time there is change in props. This caused infinite calls.

#### Solution 1

If you want to call `fetchIsProductLiked` after *products* data has been fetched, it is better to **compare** the old `products` data with the new one in `componentWillReceiveProps` as below:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.products !== this.props.products) {
    nextProps.products.forEach((product) => {
      this.props.fetchIsProductLiked(product.id);
    });
  }
}
```

Note: you should start using [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) as `componentWillReceiveProps` is getting [deprecated](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops).

---

#### Issue 2

> isProductLikedData state in reducer doesn't get updated properly.

It is **not** getting updated because you have used `map`. [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns a *new array* (having elements returned from the callback) of the **same** length (**but** you expected to add a new element).

#### Solution 2

If you want to update the data only when it is not already present in the State, you can use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if the data exists. And, push the new data using spread syntax when it returned *false*:

```
case "FETCH_IS_PRODUCT_LIKED_SUCCESS": {
  return {
    ...state,
    fetching: false,
    fetched: true,
    isProductLikedData: state.isProductLikedData.some(
      (d) => d.productId === action.payload.productId
    )
      ? state.isProductLikedData
      : [...state.isProductLikedData, action.payload],
  };
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ajeet. This is what I wanted to do. 
Issue 1 is solved perfectly, but `.some` is not updating state as I expected: It returns boolean instead of `state.isProductLikedData` or `[...state.isProductLikedData, action.payload]`.

Comment: Correct. The boolean value is stored as a value of isProductLikedData.
This is how I wrote: `isProductLikedData: state.isProductLikedData.some((data) => data.productId === action.payload.productId ? state.isProductLikedData : [...state.isProductLikedData,.action.payload])`

Comment: Oh, got it. Use the boolean, the return of `.some`, to update the state conditionally! This works! Thank you so much!